# Update the models time to time in asp.net core 5.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86MgR.png)**But I don't know how to update the model when the database has been edit.
add new table(modelsTest)
I using CLI commands**

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\v11.0;Database=xxx;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxxx;Integrated Security=false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t modelsTest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86MgR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to update the model when the database has been edited. I am using CLI commands

You can try to use the Force flag (--force or -f) to overwrite these existing files of generated model class, like below.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=xxx;Database=xxx;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxxx;Integrated Security=false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t modelsTest -f
```

For detailed information about `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` command, you can check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold